# Find prime which is generating longest primes sequence using p(n+1)=(p(n)^2+1)/2

Tags: code-challenge, primes

Consider following recurrence relation:

```
p[n + 1] = (p[n]^2 + 1) / 2
```

If `p[1]`, `p[2]`, ..., `p[k]` are primes and `p[k+1]` is not, then `k` is length of sequence starting with `p[1]`.
For example, if `p[1] = 3`, then `p[2] = 5, p[3] = 13, p[4] = 85 = 5 * 17`, thus length of sequence is 3.

## Goal

Write program which find number producing longest sequence you can find.
Give in your answer starting number, sequence length, source code and time in which program executes.

If multiple answers with same sequence length, then one with greater starting integer wins.
If even starting integer is same, then one with smaller executing time wins.
If you have taken starting integer for your program from another answer, then you should add its time. Picking starting integer at random is disallowed.

Winner will selected 1 week after first answer posted.

Comment: What happens if several people come up with the same number? Can you just make a brute force solution that runs infinitely?

Comment: Sure I will attempt to do this. But first provide a proof that there exists such a longest sequence.

Comment: I'm not even sure every sequence is finite...

Comment: Another good reason to treat `1` as not a prime. `(1^2 + 1) / 2 = 1`

Comment: @JanDvorak Seeing that this is a code-challenge, I'm pretty sure the OP is looking for the "longest sequence you can find".

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, I meant that way. There can be sequence of any length, I want largest you can find. However I've done some brute-force on small primes and it seems that longer sequences become more rare.

Comment: You might want to add some form of tie-breaker though in case two people do find the same maximum sequence.

Comment: I think execution time is a good tie-breaker but it needs to be specified better. a) Who is going to measure execution time? Different users use different machines and will report different times. b) Execution time for what? Once you run it, you know that you can skip the parts you've already checked.

Comment: @MartinBüttner By execution time I meant total time program spent on finding number. If you have taken starting number from another answer it will be more fair to add that's answer time. However picking starting values at random is disallowed.

Comment: Can I just make a program that prints the sequence http://oeis.org/A105318? And I do not think that we will get here any more of those numbers, because I am sure some mathematicians tried hard enough, you will have to find a sequence that is longer than the one starting at 2185103796349763249 and that is a pretty big prime...

Comment: @flawr I think it's not interesting) When writing this question, I thought up random sequence. However it seems that think up something that haven't been before is difficult...

Comment: You might be able to improve this by looking for the latest occurrence of the longest sequence. There will probably be more 6-prime sequence before that 7-prime sequence. Now these might all be known as well, but it would at least already break some ties and the answers couldn't be directly read off OEIS.

Comment: I don't think Dennis' question has been answered yet, and until it is answered it's not clear to me what you want.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The tie breakers are specified now, aren't they?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I don't see how that answers the question about a program which loops indefinitely. And there's potential for an infinite escalation in programs which start looking at `n+2` where `n` is the current best starting point, so the tie-breakers don't really solve the problem they aim to solve either.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I suppose the deadline does that.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, that's an awful solution. It's understandable that someone should stop updating the accepted answer when they stop frequenting the site, but as a general rule questions should not discriminate against people who come across the site in the future.

Comment: @PeterTaylor yeah, I can agree with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mathematica, 66th 6-prime sequence starting at 178,308,225,421

```
best = {0, 0}
start = TimeUsed[];
For[i = 1, True, i++,
 p = Prime@i;
 length = 0;
 q = p;
 While[PrimeQ@q,
  ++length;
  q = (q^2 + 1)/2;
  ];
 If[length > best[[1]],
  Print[{best = {length, p}, TimeUsed[] - start}]];
 ]
best
TimeUsed[] - start
```

That's a fairly trivial exhaustive search. The search doesn't terminate, so you need to abort it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> after which it'll tell you how long it has run in total.

Some timings on my machine

```
Length    Starting Prime    Cumulative Time

4         271               0.002 s
5         169,219           0.297 s
6         356,498,179       692.1 s ~ 11.5 min
```

The search for 7 primes is still running. (After 110 hours I'm still an order of magnitude below the next result as given by OEIS.)

**Edit:** I got a moderate speed-up by ditching the lookup table.

**Edit:** The search has been running all night. This time I kept track of how all n-prime sequences before the first (n+1)-prime sequence. I also switched to `NextPrime` but I think it's actually slower - of course, I'll need it if I keep this running over the weekend.

Here is some data:

If `m(n)` is the number of n-prime sequences before the first (n+1)-prime sequence, then m(n) progresses like {1, 0, 4, 10, 55, >65}.

The first 5-prime sequence starts at 169,219 and took 0.3s. The last 5-prime sequence (before the 6-prime ones start) starts at 350,505,151 and took 680s to find. While the distance between two consecutive 5-prime sequences is usually on the order of 10<sup>6</sup>, the two most closely spaced such sequences start at 222,193,661 and 222,266,839.

So far I've found the following 6-prime sequences:

```
 Starting Prime    Cumulative Time

    356,498,179       692.2 s ~  11.5 min
    432,448,789       860.1 s ~  14.5 min
  5,380,300,469    13,967.6 s ~   3.9 h   
 10,667,785,241    30,519.5 s ~   8.5 h
 11,238,777,509    32,353.6 s ~   9.0 h
 12,129,977,791    35,218.5 s ~   9.8 h
 23,439,934,621    71,781.2 s ~  20.0 h
     ...  29 more ...
 95,986,224,779   304,385.  s ~  84.5 h
 99,143,377,451   314,512.  s ~  87.4 h
102,928,086,161   326,881.  s ~  90.8 h
     ...   7 more ...
125,338,612,429   398,873.  s ~ 110.8 h 
     ...  18 more ...
178,308,225,421   568,694.  s ~ 158.0 h
```

As for the spacing of 6-prime sequences, the largest gap was about 11e9 between the 6th and 7th sequence. The two closest sequences were about 5e6 apart, the first one starting at 123,333,728,319 - they were found within 16 seconds of each other, when sometimes there is no new sequence for several hours. Also, there are 5 sequences starting between 33.99e9 and 34.9e9.

**Edit:** The week is over in a couple of hours, and I think 66 6-prime sequences is a good number, so I'm stopping this now.

Comment: Pretty fast you have done it) I have very similar code in Mathematica, and also found that number for 5-sequence) However they become more rare, but you have one week more to run this program)

Comment: I have suggestion. Maybe `NextPrime[]` can improve performance?

Comment: @user2992539 Thanks but it's actually a factor of 2 slower.

Comment: Probably it is faster with very large integers. And `Prime` doesn't work with integer larger than 2^42.

Comment: Probably those who found those numbers on OEIS have supercomputers or have thought up more clever algorithm.

Comment: @user2992539 Certainly the latter, but most likely both. My submission doesn't use any insight into number theory whatsoever. I'm sure if I knew more about it there would be a few trivial optimisations to speed this up a bit. I'll just leave this running until your deadline on Thursday for the fun of it, but that will still be an order of magnitude below the starting prime for the first 7-prime sequence.

Comment: There's a simple number-theoretic improvement: with the exceptions of 2, 3, and 5, all primes fall into one of 16 residue classes modulo 60. The map `p->(p^2+1)/2` takes 8 of those residue classes outside the set of 16, so you only need to consider primes which equal 1, 11, 19, 29, 31, 41, 49, or 59 modulo 60.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah, thanks! I really need to read up on number theory at some point soon. :) I'll see how much that speeds it up.

Comment: @PeterTaylor At least up to the first couple of 6-prime sequences that didn't give any substantial savings (about 10%). But thanks, I learned something. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Sage, 5 primes in 7.86 s (via [Sage Notebook](http://www.sagenb.org/home/KyleKanos/0/))

Not nearly as fast as [Martin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35463/11376), but it does work. I'm working on installing Sage onto my computer to see if it runs faster on my machine, rather than on the web.

```
def PrimePermutation(b):
    t = cputime()
    best = 0
    P = Primes()
    i=1
    while i<b:
        i=i+1
        q = P.next(i)
        r = q
        length = 0
        while q in P:
            length=length+1
            q = (q^2+1)/2
        if length > best:
            print(r, length, cputime() - t)
            best = length
        
            
PrimePermutation(4e10)
```

Returns (so far)

```
(3, 3, 0.0)
(271, 4, 0.009999999999990905)
(169219, 5, 7.860000000000014)
```